# Amazon S3 objects: is it possible to restrict public read policy to some IP adresses only ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-iam

A have a bucket with a public read policy. Now I want to restrict access to **some of the objects** in order to be accessible only from some IP adresses. Is this possible?

I also plan to add CloudFront. What should I do to keep the same settings on each object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use S3 bucket policy. But instead of individual files it will be applied to individual  folders in the bucket. You can use policy like the following:

```
  {
        "Version": "2008-10-17",
        "Id": "testPolicy",
        "Statement": [

            {
                "Sid": "1",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                    "AWS": "*"
                },
                "Action": "s3:GetObject",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/subfolder/subfolder2/*",
                "Condition": {
                    "IpAddress": {
                        "aws:SourceIp": [
                            "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx",
                            "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

User your bucket name and folder names, and IPs.

**Note:** Please try it first on a non production bucket.

Comment: Ok thanks for the response. However I really need to work on each file and not on folders. Is there any way to update directly the ACL of the object in order to restrict access to some IP adresses ?

Comment: @Dorian It is basically the same thing, but rather than having a statement with a wildcard value in the `Resource` definition, you would have multiple statements, each specifically referring to the exact resource you want the policy to apply to.

Comment: @Dorian As Mike has pointed out you can define it for individual objects also. My mistake in not stating that.