# Amazon s3 bucket policies restrict access has no effect

Tags: amazon-s3

I want restrict access file in amazon s3 from all public except  by some sites (using referer),
currently I have this bucket policies

```
{
"Id":"foosite-test",
"Statement":[
  {
     "Sid": "Allow from foosite admin",
     "Action": "s3:GetObject",
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
     "Principal": {
        "AWS":["*"]
     },
     "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
               "aws:Referer": [
              "http://www.foosite.co.uk/admin/*",
              "http://www.foosite.co.au/admin/*"
           ]
        }
     }
  }
  ]
}
```

But seems this policy doesn't have effect. I can copy paste s3 object url and still can access that file.
What's wrong with this policies?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this yet. I'm having same problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to add policy for deny also, that is to block all the other referer. I had answered similar question, but did not included the deny part in that sample policy. You can find my updated answer here: [Amazon S3 objects: is it possible to restrict public read policy to some IP adresses only ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622411/amazon-s3-objects-is-it-possible-to-restrict-public-read-policy-to-some-ip-adre/14622757#14622757)

In your case you have to use referer instead of IP.